# how to exclude some image from product gallery on front end

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, gallery-image

I am getting all the product images programmatically to create a banner slider from all of them, right now it is showing all the images that are uploaded from the admin to the specific product.

```
<?php $galleryData = $product->getData('media_gallery');
       $galleries = $galleryData['images'];
         $_media = Mage::getBaseUrl('media');
             foreach($galleries as $gal_images){ ?>
                <?php echo $all_I_mages =  $_media.'catalog/product'.$gal_images['file']; ?>
                    <div style="background-image:url(<?php echo $all_I_mages ?>);  background-position: center center;  background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: auto auto; background-color: #efefef; " >
                    </div>
             <?php   } ?>
```

Now i want to exclude some of the images from this array for example i dont want to include "small image" , "thumbnail" , and "base image"

can anyone guide what check i need to apply to solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put check something like that.

```
  if($_product->getThumbnail() != $gal_images['file'] || $_product->getSmallImage() != $gal_images['file'] || $_product->getBaseImage() != $gal_images['file']): ?>
<?php echo $all_I_mages =  $_media.'catalog/product'.$gal_images['file']; ?>
                    <div style="background-image:url(<?php echo $all_I_mages ?>);  background-position: center center;  background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: auto auto; background-color: #efefef; " >
                    </div>
<?php
  endif; ?>
```

Comment: Let me try if it works..

Comment: Qaisar Satti its not working anything else you can suggest..

Comment: did you load the product before that?

Comment: yes i did :
 <?php $_product = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
                    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product); ?>

Comment: @Xabby use and condition  or nested it then it work for you

Comment: There is not any default way to exclude that images any functions like exclude(); or remove(); from the array @Qaisar Satti

Comment: @Xabby use exclude checkbox that will do the trick for you i think you want it programitcally

Comment: Actually i only want to show "custom_images" that i have created in admin panel and all those images that are not selected and marked under any option.

Comment: @Xabby let me test and get back to you

Comment: thanks hope some thing will be figure out. i am trying too.

Comment: @Xabby no selection will directly goes to media gallery . if you want it to don't want to show in media just use  exclude checkbox also the base_image will be shown as the first image in product page. i hope that will do the trick for you.

Comment: i want to remove "thumbnail" , "small_image ", "Base_image" and just want to show "custom_image" and non_selection. if i exclude all the images they will stop showing on the other gallery under the main product image thats why it will not work..

Comment: @Xabby just use exclude for "thumbnail" , "small_image ",

Comment: @Qaisat Satti how we can get non_selection images only. as we are getting small_images like : $small_images = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product,'small_image');

Comment: `$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());

foreach ($product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) {
    echo var_export($image->getUrl());
}` using this code

Comment: Bro that is showing all the images, i just want the non_selection images only